# Python: reparenting or daemonizing a process

Tags: python, process, parent-child, daemon

I have an action-queue in which I submit different jobs to different servers remotely using ssh. e.g.

```
ssh s1 job1.py
ssh s2 job2.py
```

The problem is `job1.py` and `job2.py` can take a long time to finish and I do not want my action-queue to block. I wonder how I can somehow reparent my jobs.

My current solution is: `job1.py` uses `subprocess.Popen(['my_actual_job.py'])`. Using this, the ssh would not block, yet `my_actual_job.py` never completes. It somehow terminates long before it finishes its tasks. If I do `ssh s1 "job1.py 2>1"`, `my_actual_job.py` finishes, but it blocks my action-queue.

Anyone knows how can I somehow reparent my child processes (`my_actual_job.py`), so that the ssh can terminate but my jobs can finish their tasks in background?

I saw [PEP 3143: Standard daemon process library](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/#example-usage), but is there any better and cleaner way of doing it?

I cannot change my ssh command... I need to somehow do it in my job1.py. I did [Double Forking](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66012-fork-a-daemon-process-on-unix/), but still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing: subprocess.Popen(['nohup','my_actual_job.py']) with sending both stderr and stdout to /dev/null.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem with `Popen` is that `job1.py` will terminate without waiting for `my_actual_job.py` to finish (assuming you're never calling `p.join()` or similar); `my_actual.job.py` should then barely get started before being killed.

Have you tried asking the `ssh` process to background itself with e.g. `ssh -n s1 job1.py`?

Comment: I have no control over ssh ... I checked: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66012-fork-a-daemon-process-on-unix/... but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) for problems like this. It got really great in latest edition (3.0), with support for eventlet, canvas etc.

If Celery is too much overhead, than [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/) is better solution than Twisted in terms of complexity added to project (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048012/eventlet-or-gevent-or-stackless-twisted-pylons-django-and-sql-alchemy))

Answer (score 0):

1. You can just run your command on a server in the background, the way isn't very obvious but it's easy to use when you know the way.
   [Getting ssh to execute a command in the background on target machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142/getting-ssh-to-execute-a-command-in-the-background-on-target-machine)
2. You can run simple web server which will manage jobs on every machine. With [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) you should be able to achieve this with little code.