# Python Server Socket Without Infinite Loop?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'd like to create a class that allows sending and receiving on the same port and create an event-driven application from incoming messages while the program does it operations. I don't have much experience with sockets so I don't know how to do this. Here is my SimpleSock class that so far just binds the socket. I also put an infinite loop in there to listen for connections but know this won't work for what I want because the program won't be able to do anything besides listen.

```
import socket

class SimpleSock:

    def __init__(self, ip=None, port=None):
        if ip == None or port == None:
            print("SimpleSock cannot init without an ip and port")
        else:
            self.ip = ip
            self.port = port
            self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

            print("attempting connection to " + self.ip + " on port " + str(self.port))

            self.socket.bind((self.ip, self.port))
            self.socket.listen(5)

            print("connected")

            while True:
                (clientsocket, address) = self.socket.accept()
                #do something
```

How can I write a listen without and infinite loop? Do I need to use threads?

Comment: Yes, threads would be a good idea if your program needs to do more than listening on a socket or wants to handle a larger amount of client connections simultaneously. You could also use processes (google python multiprocessing) instead of threads.

Answer (score 0):

Event-driven network applications in Python can be built using frameworks like Python Twisted or Tornado.  You can see a comparison in another question here: [When to use Tornado, when to use Twisted / Cyclone / GEvent / other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941903/when-to-use-tornado-when-to-use-twisted-cyclone-gevent-other)

The general idea is that the framework will let you register callbacks for when events happen like data waiting on a socket, and the framework will usually be your "main loop" (so it takes over control of the main thread typically).  You do not need threads most of the time--everything can be multiplexed in a single thread so long as all your event sources are waitable using select() or similar.