# Concurrency support in python compared to C# and C++

Tags: c#, python, concurrency

I am looking for an explanation by someone who has worked in depth with both languages. Someone who has worked with C# and C++, I know C# provides a task parallel library from .Net 4.0 onwards. C++ also has a concurrent runtime library http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504870.aspx.

How can one achieve concurrency in python webapps and not spawn processes but rather threads for tasks. Assuming the user is able to manage locks etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a global interpreter lock that prevents more than one thread from executing at a time, essentially preventing concurrency.  That's why you see people spawning processes when they want concurrency in Python.  C# and C++ in contrast permit concurrent threads.

Additional information on why Python has a global interpreter lock is available at [Why the Global Interpreter Lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265687/why-the-global-interpreter-lock).

Answer (score 2):

Warning: [concurrency is not parallelism](http://blog.golang.org/concurrency-is-not-parallelism).  Warren is correct that the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) limits parallelism within a single Python process, but if the process is IO-bound a [select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html)-based application can provide sufficient concurrency *without* parallelism (Python's [asyncore](https://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html) documentation has a good discussion of the select-based workflow).

That said, Python's [Twisted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_%28software%29) framework provides future-like objects called deferreds and does multi-threading under the hood (obviously the GIL limits each process to a single thread at any given instant).  [Though some find Twisted too low level and/or deferreds to complicated for webapp development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941903/when-to-use-tornado-when-to-use-twisted-cyclone-gevent-other).

In the extreme it is possible for native code called from Python to release the GIL if the native code is not going to interact with Python objects.  For example [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) provides a rudimentary interface to C functions which releases the GIL while the C function is running.  Similar results can be achieved with other extension frameworks like [Boost.Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8011153/324493) and [SIP](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SIP).

Comment: +1 for "concurrency is not parallelism". As a side note, `asyncore` is deprecated since Python 3.6, [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) should be used instead.